# How to make MATLAB start the xtick from the very beginning?

Tags: matlab

I am plotting with MATLAB and make MATLAB to put 15 xticks on the x-label. The first xtick doesn't start from the very beginning, though.

```
xticks([1:15]);
xticklabels({'(1, 2)','(1, 3)','(2, 3)','(1, 4)','(2, 4)','(3, 4)','(1, 5)','(2, 5)','(3, 5)','(4, 5)',...
    '(1, 6)', '(2, 6)', '(3, 6)', '(4, 6)', '(5, 6)'});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is: `xlim([1:15]);`